# How to download file after redirect to same url using webclient?

Tags: c#, vb.net, redirect, download, webclient

I am trying to download a file from torcache using webclient. the problem is there is a 5 second timer and it redirects to the same url with the "referer" header and the browser downloads the file. if I try the same thing in webclient it keeps taking me to the html page rather than giving me the file.

if its without timer I think I can use the setting, 
wc.request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
wc.request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1
but that doesnt seem to work here.

anyone know how to get around this? I have been cracking my head for a while now and any help will be appreciated/ thanks.

Comment: Do you set the referrer in the second request?

Comment: thanks for your response and yes, only on the 2nd request.

Comment: here is a link if you want to play with it: http://torcache.net/torrent/71C7C35F36CAFC17A9682C8968B259A47C6BF3AB.torrent

Answer (score 0):

silly me, there was a spelling error in Referer. I used 'Referrer' instead of 'Referer'. it works once you change that. thanks.